# Is there a way to bypass the need to reference self in an argument (Python)

Tags: python, oop, pyautogui, pynput

The purpose of my code is to create and print a list of all the keyboard and mouse interactions that occur. The code was working, but then I decided to convert it into a class. From there, I was not able to reference the functions because it considered self to be the first argument.

Here is the code with the class that does not work.

```
import pyautogui
from pynput.mouse import Listener
MouseListener = Listener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
KeyboardListener = Listener
from pynput import keyboard

######################
#
# m = move
# p = mouse press
# r = mouse release
# d = scroll down
# u = scroll up
# 1 = key down
# 2 = key up
#
######################

temp = []
class Recorder():
    #record mouse movement
    def on_move(self, x, y):
        temp.append('m{0}'.format(
            (x, y)))

    #record mouse click
    def on_click(self, x, y, button, pressed):
        temp.append('{0}{1}'.format(
            'p' if pressed else 'r',
            (x, y)))

    #record mouse scroll
    def on_scroll(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        temp.append('{0}{1}'.format(
            'd' if dy < 0 else 'u',
            (x, y)))

    #record keyboard press
    def on_press(self, key):
        try:
            temp.append('1({0})'.format(
                key.char))
        except AttributeError:
            temp.append('1({0})'.format(
                key))

    #record keyboard release and end if esc
    def on_release(self, key):
        temp.append('2({0})'.format(
            key))
        if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            print(temp)
            keyboard_listener.stop()
            mouse_listener.stop()
            return False

mouse_listener = MouseListener(
    on_move=Recorder.on_move,
    on_click=Recorder.on_click,
    on_scroll=Recorder.on_scroll)

keyboard_listener = KeyboardListener(
    on_press=Recorder.on_press,
    on_release=Recorder.on_release)

keyboard_listener.start()
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
mouse_listener.join()
```

And below is the code that performs properly.

```
import pyautogui
from pynput.mouse import Listener
MouseListener = Listener
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
KeyboardListener = Listener
from pynput import keyboard

##########
#
# m = move
# p = mouse press
# r = mouse release
# d = scroll down
# u = scroll up
# 1 = key down
# 2 = key up
#
##########

temp = []

#mouse recorder
def on_move(x, y):
    temp.append('m{0}'.format(
        (x, y)))

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    temp.append('{0}{1}'.format(
        'p' if pressed else 'r',
        (x, y)))

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    temp.append('{0}{1}'.format(
        'd' if dy < 0 else 'u',
        (x, y)))

#keyboard recorder
def on_press(key):
    try:
        temp.append('1({0})'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        temp.append('1({0})'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    temp.append('2({0})'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        print(temp)
        keyboard_listener.stop()
        mouse_listener.stop()
        return False

#activation
mouse_listener = MouseListener(
    on_move=on_move,
    on_click=on_click,
    on_scroll=on_scroll)

keyboard_listener = KeyboardListener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)

keyboard_listener.start()
mouse_listener.start()
keyboard_listener.join()
mouse_listener.join()
```

Comment: You forgot to instantiate `Recorder`, that's why the methods are not bound to an instance and Python complains that it wants the first argument to explicitly be an instance of `Recorder`.

Comment: "The code was working, but then I decided to convert it into a class." why? All you're doing is using the class as a namespace. What's the point?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the decorator `@staticmethod` for this. Add `@staticmethod` above the functions in question. For example:

```
class Recorder:
    #record mouse movement
    @staticmethod
    def on_move(x, y,temp):
        temp.append('m{0}'.format((x, y)))
```

You can now use the function without instantiating an object.
Call the function with:

```
Recorder.on_move(x,y,temp)
```

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)